# Android Studio can't find dependency

Tags: android, git, maven, gradle, jcenter

I pushed an .aar artifact to Jcenter repository through bintray and gradle. I followed [this tutorial](https://github.com/wingoku/gradle-jcenter-publish) step by step, the only thing *I did different was I didn't give the correct Github repository link because the git repository is private*. Now I am stuck at step 16. After I pushed my artifact file. I tried to follow the step 16 however that option isn't working in Bintray website. I tried to access my artifact as a dependency in another project but gradle can't find it and gives `"Failed to resolve com.wingoku.tickers:1.0.0"`. What am I doing wrong?

Best Regards

**EDIT**:

I clicked on **Add To JCenter** last night and clicked the checkbox and provided my Groupid and it said `"Message sent to bintray"`. Still When I click on Add to jcenter it asks me the same thing. And I still can't follow step 16 because  **MavenControl** is still no clickable.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that this aar is in jcenter?  I can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

Your request for inclusion to JCenter is still pending or was rejected. My best guess will be that's because you don't have correct GitHub repository link. The free service in Bintray is for OSS projects only and providing the source control link is a mandatory requirement.

Comment: So how private reopsitory owners push .aar to jcenter?

Comment: They can't. JCenter is for OSS components only. You're more than welcome to create a premium package in Bintray and distribute your package from your own repo.

Comment: OK. So I created a repo on Github and provided its link. Now When I push to bintray it says `"I have released versoin 1.0.3 or tickerupdate4"` However I still can't access it in a project via build.gradle. What wrong am I doing now?

Comment: What package in bintray we are talking about? Can you please share the link?

Comment: Still not in JCenter. Did you request the inclusion again?

Comment: yes I did several times. This time I have put a git repository link but still MavenCentral option isn't working as shown in the picture.

Comment: The vcs link you added doesn't match the package. You'll get an answer from Bintray support in a few minutes.

Comment: so the only workaround I can think of is, I will have to create a sample project with same bundle/packageID and make it a public repository and provide that link to the Bintray inorder for them to approve my artifacts, Yes?

Comment: Now I am getting this message upon clicking maven central sync `Last Sync Errors: Failed to promote repository: central_bundles-3756. Server response: *User 'alfjam' missing 'promote' permission for staging profile: 7edbe315063867 Dropping existing partial staging repository.`

Comment: I think it's because the sonatype oss isn't approving my project repository. They asked me if I was the owner of the domain, which I am hence I said "Yes" but still there is no response from them and the approval of the repository is still pending. How can I approve that repository?